# Make an SVG element have greedy height

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to display a square root with an argument in pure CSS. My current effort is right here:

https://jsfiddle.net/29L4ehef/62/

but it only works when argument has a particular font-size. When I increase the font-size, the square root symbol no longer keeps up vertically. What can I change so that the unicode square root symbols keeps up with the height of the argument? Please note that in my project I cannot predict what's in the argument of the square root. It could end up being a tall fraction, etc. So I hope that there is a way for the SVG element to stay in sync with the height of the argument.

Many thanks in advance!

```
<span>
  <svg width="5em" height="2em" class="symbol" class="square-root-symbol" viewBox="0 0 10 14" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <text x="0" y="14" font-size="15px">√</text>
  </svg>
  <span class="argument">
    A
  </span>
</span>

.symbol {
  height: 5em;
  width: 3.4em;
  margin-right: -0.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.argument {
  font-size: 4em; /* CHANGE ME - ONLY WORKS FOR 4em */
  border-top: .05em solid black;
  padding-left: .15em;
  padding-right: .25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to calculate the sizes you need using the SVG DOM.

Comment: Will that involve JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it would involve javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I changed your HTML:

```
<span class="symbol-container">
  <svg  class="symbol" class="square-root-symbol" viewBox="0 0 10 14" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <text x="0" y="14" font-size="15px">√</text>
  </svg>
  <span class="argument">
    A
  </span>
</span>
```

and CSS:

```
.symbol-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 10em;
}

.symbol {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.argument {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 10em; /* CHANGE ME - ONLY WORKS FOR 4em */
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't quite work. If I were to change the font-size of the argument to a smaller value (e.g. 2em) then the the square root symbol doesn't change its height.

Comment: `.symbol-container` and `.argument` should use the same values for the height and font-size accordingly

Comment: Is it possible to achieve if I don't know the contents of the argument beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give your SVG a size that's relative to the current font size:

```css
.equation {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.symbol {
  width: 0.75em;
  margin-right: -0.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.argument {
  border-top: .05em solid black;
  padding-left: .15em;
  padding-right: .25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="equation">
  <svg class="symbol" class="square-root-symbol" viewBox="0 0 10 14" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <text x="0" y="14" font-size="15px">√</text>
  </svg>
  <span class="argument">
    A
  </span>
</span>
```